# Passing a function as a parameter through 2 directives in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

I have a list of Task items:

template:

```
<div> 
    <p class="assignment">{{ task.Assignment }}</p>
    <p class="assignment">{{ task.Assignee }}</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="backTask()"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="advanceTask()"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="deleteTask()"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
</div>
```

which are inside a taskList:

template:

```
<div id="{{ status }}" class="col-md-4 taskList">
    <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item flex-column">To Do</li>
    <li ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter:{Status: 0}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">
            <task 
                    task="task"
                    back-Task="backTask()"
                    advance-Task="advanceTask()"
                    delete-Task="deleteTask()">
            </task>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I need to pass the back, advance and delete task functions from the initial call:

```
<task-List 
    status="todo" 
    tasks="tasks"
    back-Task="backTask($event, task)"
    advance-Task="advanceTask($event, task)"
    delete-Task="deleteTask($event, task)">
</task-List>
```

to each individual task (so that each task's button can change its properties). With my current code when the button is pressed both $event and task are undefined on the final call, what's the correct way to pass down functions as parameters in a situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that when you instantiate task-list you're calling the functions straight away `back-Task="backTask($event, task)"`.

Instead, you should pass references to the functions `back-Task="backTask"` and call the functions in the ng-clicks, in the Task template, `ng-click="backTask($event, task)"`

Task template

```
<div> 
    <p class="assignment">{{ task.Assignment }}</p>
    <p class="assignment">{{ task.Assignee }}</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="backTask($event, task)"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="advanceTask($event, task)"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="deleteTask($event, task)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
</div>
```

Task list template

```
<div id="{{ status }}" class="col-md-4 taskList">
    <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item flex-column">To Do</li>
    <li ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter:{Status: 0}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">
            <task 
                    task="task"
                    back-Task="backTask"
                    advance-Task="advanceTask"
                    delete-Task="deleteTask">
            </task>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Task list instantiation

```
 <task-List 
    status="todo" 
    tasks="tasks"
    back-Task="backTask"
    advance-Task="advanceTask"
    delete-Task="deleteTask">
</task-List>
```

Hope that works and that makes sense :)

P.S. I'm not sure how you defined your directives, but keep in mind that when defining a directive name or an attribute, you would write it in camel case in the js declaration `e.g. taskList` and in lower-case-dash-separated in a template `e.g. <task-list>`

Comment: This is something I had already tried, assignment and assignee are both displayed properly, but clicking on the buttons doesn't make any calls, which is why I thought that I needed to pass the functions with the parameters from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

For the `task` component, use one-way binding with `'<'` for inputs and expression binding with `'&'` for outputs:

```
app.component("task", {
    bindings: { item: '<',
                backTask: '&',
                advanceTask: '&',
                deleteTask: '&'
              },
    controller: function() {
        this.backClick = (event) => this.backTask({$event: event});
        this.advanceClick = (event) => this.advanceTask({$event: event});
        this.deleteClick = (event) => this.deleteTask({$event: event});
    },
    template: 
        `<div> 
            <p class="assignment">{{ $ctrl.item.Assignment }}</p>
            <p class="assignment">{{ $ctrl.item.Assignee }}</p>
            <button ng-click="$ctrl.backClick($event)"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
            <button ng-click="$ctrl.advanceClick($event)"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
            <button ng-click="$ctrl.deleteClick($event)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
        </div>`
});
```

Similarly for the `taskList` component:

```
app.component("taskList", {
    bindings: { status: '<',
                tasks: '<',
                backTask: '&',
                advanceTask: '&',
                deleteTask: '&',
              },
    controller: function() {
        this.backClick = (event,task) => backTask({$event:event, $task:task});
        this.advanceClick = (event,task) => advanceTask({$event:event, $task:task});
        this.deleteClick = (event,task) => advanceTask({$event:event, $task:task});
    },
    template:
        `<div id="{{ $ctrl.status }}" class="col-md-4 taskList">
            <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item flex-column">To Do</li>
            <li ng-repeat="task in $ctrl.tasks | filter:{Status: 0}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">
                <task 
                    item="task"
                    back-task="$ctrl.backClick($event,task)"
                    advance-task="$ctrl.advanceClick($event,task)"
                    delete-task="$ctrl.deleteClick($event,task)">
                </task>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>`
});
```

Usage:

```
<task-list 
    status="vm.todo" 
    tasks="vm.tasks"
    back-task="vm.backTask($event,$task)"
    advance-task="vm.advanceTask($event,$task)"
    delete-task="vm.deleteTask($event,$task)">
</task-list>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture).